# BxSlider copy images and append to new element

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

I'm using Bxslider and I want to have a section underneath my slideshow which shows all the images in the slideshow as thumbnails so for e.g at the moment there's 4 placeholder images in my slideshow... so below will be a section with those 4 images showing as thumbnail images.

I've managed to grab the images but struggling to wrap them in HTML list elements as it just outputs an object.

Any ideas?

JSFIDDLE
https://jsfiddle.net/hy3w0rxz/1/

HTML

```
<!-- Main Slideshow -->
<ul class="bxslider bxslider--small">
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/960x720"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/960x720"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/960x720"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/960x720"></li>
</ul>

<div id="bxslider-thumbnails">
</div>
```

JS

```
// BX Slider initiate
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    mode: 'fade',
    captions: true,
});


$(document).ready(function(){
    var slides = $(".bxslider--small").find("img");
        $(slides).each(function(i, value) {
            var slidesOutput = "<li>" + value + "</li>";
            $(slidesOutput).clone().appendTo("#bxslider-thumbnails");
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you append, you are actually moving the element not copying it. The most common way to copy elements is by `cloneNode()` (JS) or `clone()` (jQ).

<kbd>**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/8L1b8mnj/1/)**</kbd>

#### SNIPPET

```js
// BX Slider initiate
var bx = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  mode: 'fade',
  captions: true
});

// This grabs the images from the main slideshow and put them into the bxslider thumbnails, but it removes the images from the main slideshow instead of copying them. When using `.each()` the most effective way to reference the current element is to use `this` or `$(this)`.



$(document).ready(function() {
  var slides = $(".bxslider-small img");
  var bxt = document.getElementById('bxslider-thumbnails');
  $(slides).each(function(i, value) {
    var that = this;
    var slidesOutput = this.cloneNode(true);
    bxt.appendChild(slidesOutput);
  });
});
```

```css
.bxslider img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>

<!-- Main Slideshow -->
<ul class="bxslider bxslider-small">
  <li>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/000/fff?text=1">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/00f/eee?text=2">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/0e0/111?text=3">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/f00/fff?text=4">
  </li>
</ul>

<!-- This slideshow should grab the main slideshow images and add them to the id below -->
<div id="bxslider-thumbnails">
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

See the live example below:

```js
// BX Slider initiate
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  pagerCustom: '#bxslider-thumbnails',
  auto: true
});
```

```css
a.active {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 0px !important;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Main Slideshow -->
<ul class="bxslider">
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/960x720/CCCCCC&text=First+Slide"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/960x720/CCCCCC&text=Second+Slide"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/960x720/CCCCCC&text=Third+Slide"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/960x720/CCCCCC&text=Fourth+Slide"></li>
</ul>

<!-- Thumbnails Slideshow -->
<div id="bxslider-thumbnails">
  <a data-slide-index="0" href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/CCCCCC&text=1" /></a>
  <a data-slide-index="1" href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/CCCCCC&text=2" /></a>
  <a data-slide-index="2" href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/CCCCCC&text=3" /></a>
  <a data-slide-index="3" href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/CCCCCC&text=4" /></a>
</div>
```

via **[bxslider Thumbnail pager Next prev buttons](http://jsfiddle.net/lesson8/jx6ps/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=jx6ps)**.